# How can I make a "for-loop" with a specific number of loops in Qweb?

Tags: xml, for-loop, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I would like to make a loop to print elements an exact amount of times. Something like this:

```
<t t-for="o.label_qty" >
...
</t>
```

Where `o.label_qty` is an integer number.

But I can use only a `t-foreach` loop in qweb:

```
<t t-foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="l" >
...
</t>
```

Is there a way to do this?

If not I'm thinking the only solution is to create a dummy list with `o.label_qty` elements and write it in the foreach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `t-foreach` directive accepts a Python expression.
So, you could use `range()` just like in Python `for` loops:

```
<t t-foreach="range(o.label_qty)" t-as="l">
...
</t>
```

Comment: if *o.label_qty* store float value then it will raise error *TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.* So we have do type casting from *float* to *int*

Comment: For Python 3.x, I believe we have to use `list(range())`

Answer (score 7):

yes it totally possible in Odoo Qweb Report you just need to add the below way to do somethings like this

```
     <t t-foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="l" >
         <td class="col-xs-1">
             <span t-esc="l_index+1"/>
         </td>
     </t>
```

hear the `<span> tag` is print the total no of times loop will be executed while we are printing our qweb report. 
**index** is the part of `Qweb Template Engine` so hear it is always start with `0 element`.

I hope my answer may help you :)

Answer (score 3):

*range()* function will raise error for floating value.

For example:

```
>>>a=1.0
>>>range(a)
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

For dynamic variable loops, there are two possibility for looping with specific number.

1. Integer number (as answered by @Daniel Reis)
2. Float number (try with following)

   ```
   <t t-set="i" t-value="int(o.label_qty)"/>
   <t t-foreach="range(i)" t-as="l">
   ...
   </t>
   ```

[for more details of range() function.](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

Comment: You are right Odedra. But I specified in my question that `o.label_qty` is a integer number so I think the answer of Daniel Reis is enough. Thanks for your contribution